# Insert DataFrame into SQL table with AUTO_INCREMENT column

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I have a MySQL table which includes a column that is `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
CREATE TABLE features (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(30),
  value DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

I created a `DataFrame` and wanted to insert it into this table.

```
case class Feature(name: String, value: Double)
val rdd: RDD[Feature]
val df = rdd.toDF()
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("jdbc:mysql://...", "features", new Properties)
```

I get the error, `Column count doesn’t match value count at row 1`. If I delete the `id` column it works. How could I insert this data into the table without changing the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include an `id` field in the DataFrame, but its value will be ignored and replaced with the auto-incremented ID. That is:

```
case class Feature(id: Int, name: String, value: Double)
```

Then just set `id` to 0, or any number when you create a `Feature`.

Comment: Sorry it's not a straight answer, but I barely understand the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have known why the error happened while I still don't how to do. Next I will try my best to explain clearly. In my table, I have 5 columns which include `id` column. However, in my `DataFrame`, I have only 4 columns, and my `DataFrame` will map `MySQL Table` just the first 4 columns and left the fifth columns doesn't map. With `SQL`, I know how to insert but with spark, I dont know how to do even I had search for the APIs. I hope you can understand or I can send you e-mail if you can understand Chinese.

Comment: Okay. So the question is basically how to use `insertIntoJDBC` with an `auto_increment` field. Try inserting 0 for the `id`. Maybe the database will sort it out.

Comment: I know it's bad to ask another unrelated question under this question, but could you tell how to follow you? I don't know how to follow people in stackoverflow

Comment: I don't think you can follow people on Stack Overflow. You can subscribe to a *tag* though! I recommend subscribing to [tag:apache-spark]!

Comment: (I'll try to edit the question and my answer to be a bit clearer when I have some time.)

Comment: I've edited the question and the answer. Can you please check to make sure it is correct? I tried to remove some incidental bits from the question (we don't need 5 columns for the example) but also include the database schema which is pretty important. And I wanted to switch to `write.jdbc` from `insertIntoJDBC` (which is deprecated), so that the question does not become obsolete in the future. You can compare with the old version at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31315806/revisions. Feel free to make any edits you think would be useful!

Comment: Hi,Daniel, thanks for you kind edit. It is actual right , but in your answer, I think `id` should be placed in the first place because what we insert should  map the `table` we created.

Comment: in my case, the id must be at the first, following the order of table column define

Comment: Thanks, I've moved `id` to the first place.